# How to parent shutter lens rig to object

Tags: rigging, objects, constraints, parent, optimization

So I created a shutter lens rig for an eyeball that works fine, but when I try to parent it to an eyeball on my character it doesn't keep transform and I'm not sure why. No matter how I try to parent it, I'm getting weird results.

[image]

[image]

The lens is made up of 7 different moving objects that all rotate on a median point and have a copy rotations constraint to an empty object. Each with the following settings:

[image]

The empty has a limit rotation constraint with the following setting:
[image]

My goal is to have the whole rig parented to the eyeball so that it can follow along with eyeball rotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

You need to use local space in all constraints to get what you want.

- Clear the controller rotation(Empty.002),
- Apply the shutters rotation(Circle.001-010),
- Parent the other objects to the protrusion(Sphere.085) and
- Change all constraints.

[image]